# How can I use my AccountManager from a different app?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, accountmanager

I was following [Udinic's guide](https://github.com/Udinic/AccountAuthenticator) to make an `AccountManager`.  I can use it fine in the app where the account manager files are stored, but I cannot access it from other apps.  I can access the accounts themselves and use `GetAuthToken()` and everything works that way, but I cannot seem to add a new account.  It will not call the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`.

I noticed in the example apps' manifests that they reference the authenticator app's service and activities.  I have tried to do this in my other app, but it will not compile with the service in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.redacted.routines" android:versionCode="8" android:versionName="1.1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <application android:label="@string/ApplicationName" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="com.redacted.authenticator.AccountAuthenticatorActivity" />
    <service android:name="com.redacted.authenticator.AuthenticatorService">
      <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

It wants me to also add the xml files associated with the authenticator, and I do not think that is right.  If I do add them, it will compile but I still cannot launch the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`.  I believe the reason I am having trouble has something to do with my manifests, as my other apps need to be aware of the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` and `AuthenticatorService`.

I need to be able to add a new account from my other apps.  When I call `AddAccount()` I can debug the app that the account manager is located in and I can see the `AddAccount()` code being executed.  But I get no errors, the activity just does not launch.  How am I supposed to use AccountManager from other apps?

Comment: So problem is that you want to launch your account manager app from your other apps to achieve adding account?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.  I found a workaround though, and I posted my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997861/why-is-my-accountauthenticatoractivity-not-launching-when-triggered-by-another-a